# Como arreglo banner de perfil?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

tengo un problema en el sitio web que ha creado mi programador. En esta pagina, cada usuario tiene su perfil. En su header se encuentra la imagen de perfil y el cover de cada usuario.
El problema es el siguiente: en resoluciones grandes el banner se muestra cortado a un 95%, pero en menores y asi como en dispositivos se muestra cortado a un 60& aprox.

Este es el codigo en php:

```
                        <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <!-- new code -->
                        <?php if(file_exists('uploads/vendor_banner_image/banner_'.$vendor_id.'.jpg')){?>
                            <div class="vendor_cover_img" style="background-image: url(<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/vendor_banner_image/banner_<?php echo $vendor_id;?>.jpg"></div>
                        <?php }else{?>
                            <img class="slide-img"  src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/vendor_banner_image/default.jpg"/> 
                        <?php }?>
                    </div>
```

Y este en css:

```
}
.vendor_cover_img {
  height: 110px;
  background-size: cover;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#main-slider .owl-stage-outer{
  border-right: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  border-left: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
}
```

Imagen en vista de un dispositivo movil, para que tengan una idea la imagen es de 720px x 120px[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya agradezco su ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

**Solucionado**
Lo que hice fue agregarle un `height` distinto por cada resolucion. Mediante `media query` en css

Comment: en vez de citar lo que hiciste, por favor añade el codigo resultante.. si no , parece un comentario y no una respuesta. Un saludo

Comment: Malcolm, has de editar la respuesta.